When clicking on a facebook post, sometimes I receive fb deeplink and sometimes the universal link of my app
Since recently, Universal links were working well with our app but recently for some users while clicking on a facebook post we receive via func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) this deeplink  -> fbxxxxxxxxx(FacebookAppId present in the app project)://authorize#target_url=universaLinkOfMyApp.
However, others users seems to still receive the universal link directly via func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) like before. (That's how we handle it until now)
Is there something else to configure to avoid this two behavior or I need to handle them both?
Thanks in advance for helping!

It seems I need to use Bolt to handle App Link according to this url : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios but this post doesn't seem recent, so why before it was not needed and now yes? Any idea?
